# Asynchronous image download succeeded but image does not appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uiimageview

I am writing an app that  displays images from url in a view. The idea is that  when the view appears, image is dowloaded and it actualizes a UIImamgeView in the view.

I am using a Asyncrounse method in this way:

```
 -(void)downloadASyncro:(NSString*)urlLink{

        NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlLink];

        [self downloadImageWithURL:imageURL completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
            if (succeeded) {

                NSLog(@"scaricaImmagineASyncro  Succeded=  %@",image);
                picView.image = image;
            }
            else {
                //default image
                picView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_old.jpg"];

            }
        }];

     }
```

the  downloadImageWithURL method is:

```
- (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image))completionBlock
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if ( !error )
                               {
                                   UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                   completionBlock(YES,image);
                               } else{
                                   completionBlock(NO,nil);
                               }
                           }];
}
```

When I call the method:

```
[self downloadASyncro:link];
```

and the operation sees end with success (NSLOG),    picView.image = image; should actualize the view showing the image downloaded , should not it? But immage does not appear...

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does downloadASyncro return?

Comment: What's the frame of the imageView?

Comment: @EmeryFramboise how can get a return value from a Async method?

Comment: You should update the UIImageView on the main thread.  Are you sure you're doing that?

Comment: Sorry doxsi, that was vague, I ment, what does 'image' contain?

Comment: Where are you creating `picView`?

Comment: @CharliePrice, no I am not.How can check it?

Comment: I'll post an answer so I can include some code...

Comment: @CharliePrice the block will be called on the main thread only. My guess is that problem is with picView's frame/bounds or allocation. Is it a iVar because it is not allocated in downloadASyncro method?